# Issues created after a particular time to be returned in Github API

Tags: github, github-api

In the Issues call in the Github API, I want to call issues 'created' after a particular time in my app. But the parameter list gives only issues 'updated at or after' a particular time. Is there any way for me to obtain issues created at or after a particular time? 
Thanks! https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the Issues Search API for that:

https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues

Notice that it supports filtering by `created` and sorting by the same parameter.